# Submitting a form works when values are put in manually, but not through a script

Tags: javascript

I am trying to fill and submit a form through Javascript:

```
var user_criteria = {
    bu: '%',
    voucher: '%',
    invoice: '%',
    vendor_id: '%',
    requester: '%',
    vendor_name: '%havas%', 
};

var controls = {
    bu: document.getElementById("InputKeys_BUSINESS_UNIT"),
    voucher: document.getElementById("InputKeys_VOUCHER_ID"),
    invoice: document.getElementById("InputKeys_INVOICE_ID"),
    vendor_id: document.getElementById("InputKeys_VENDOR_ID"),
    requester: document.getElementById("InputKeys_REQUESTOR_ID"),
    vendor_name: document.getElementById("InputKeys_NAME1"),
    search_button: document.getElementById("#ICOK"),
};

function search(criteria) {
    controls.bu.value = criteria.bu;
    controls.voucher.value = criteria.voucher;
    controls.invoice.value = criteria.invoice;
    controls.vendor_id.value = criteria.vendor_id;
    controls.requester.value = criteria.requester;
    controls.vendor_name.value = criteria.vendor_name;
    controls.search_button.click()
};

search(user_criteria)
```

However, no results will be returned for this search, event though if I fill the inputs manually, the same search will return some results.

It seems that for some reason the script that is executed when the search button is clicked (I don't have access to it) does not see the values in the input, even though I can see the values changing on the screen and also `document.getElementById(some_input).value` will return the value that was sent by my script.

Why does the search work with manual input, but not when the values are put in through the script? How to make it work?

Inputs look like this:

```
<input type="text" name="InputKeys_BUSINESS_UNIT" id="InputKeys_BUSINESS_UNIT" tabindex="11" value="" class="PSEDITBOX" style="width:46px; " maxlength="5">
```

The search button:

```
<input type="button" class="PSPUSHBUTTON" value="View Results" id="#ICOK" onclick="submitAction_win2(this.form,'#ICOK');" tabindex="17">
```

EDIT: as per suggestions from comments, I have checked what form data is sent in the request. If I input the values manually, they will be included in the form data, but if the values are input by script - not. But I don't understand why.

Comment: Can you please create a reproducable snippet?

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/69kub3z7/), the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: I will note that although it works, using `#ICOK` as the `id` of your button is a Bad Idea™. :-) Again, it works if you use `getElementById` as you are, but you don't want that `#` there. If you ever wanted to use a CSS selector for that button, it would be quite awkward to write. Whereas if you just use`id="ICOK"`, then `getElementById("ICOK")`, you can also use a nice simple CSS selector if necessary (`querySelector("#ICOK")`). (The `#` in `#ICOK` indicates it's an ID selector.)

Comment: You should inspect your website with webdeveloper tools and can check what request is sent to the server ...

Comment: @derpishcer: The input values are not included in the request when they are filled in by the script. However,  in case of manual input - they are.

Comment: show the code for `submitAction_win2`. Or place a breakpoint within this method and check the parameters. Because I'm not really sure what `this` resp `this.form` resolves to in an onclick eventhandler